# Typescript Definition. When a class needs to be dynamic?

Tags: typescript

One of the Definition files I am trying to write is a Filter.  The filter code is loaded from a JS file initially, then the string name of that filter is used.

```
export class Filter
{
    do stuff...
}
```

The problem is that each filter has its own properties.

For example, a "Marble" filter might have a "frequency" value whereas a "BlurX" filter has a "blur" value.

And so:

```
//loaded MarbleFilter.js as a script previously
var filter: Filter = new Filter("Marble");
filter.frequency = 10   //error
```

How can I deal with this situation? There are 12 filter types, so maybe I could do something with interfaces? But, I do not understand how others are supposed to know this :

`var filter: IMarbleFilter = <IMarbleFilter>new Filter("Marble");`

If I did go with the above example, would it be apt to make an empty IFilter?  So IMarbleFilter implements IFilter and so does Filter?

I would appreciate any advice. I asked locally in my project, but no response from the community so trying you Gurus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this with TypeScript *classes* because a `new` operator on classes returns an instance of the class. But you can do this with *interfaces* using specialized signatures:

```
interface Filter{}
interface MarbleFilter extends Filter{ frequency: number; }
interface BlurFilter extends Filter{}

interface FilterCreator{
    new (arg:"Marble"): MarbleFilter;
    new (arg:"Blur"): BlurFilter;
    new (arg:string):Filter;
}

var Filter:FilterCreator; 
// TODO: create a javascript variable that satisfies
// the specified interface

// usage: 
var filter = new Filter("Marble");
filter.frequency = 10; // okay
```

Comment: Ahh Basarat I follow you :D Thanks for this! It actually makes sense, but I would never have guessed it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at implementing the Command Design pattern, or something similar.

http://www.dofactory.com/javascript-command-pattern.aspx

This would allow you to write code such as:

```
SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter();
sf.Execute( new MarbleFilter( 10 ));
sf.Execute( new OtherFilter("test"));
```